# Parsing a website with BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Trying to compare avg. temperatures to actual temperatures by scraping them from: https://usclimatedata.com/climate/binghamton/new-york/united-states/usny0124

I can successfully gather the webpage's source code, but I am having trouble parsing through it to only give the values for the high temps, low temps, rainfall and the averages under the "History" tab, but I can't seem to address the right class/id without getting the only result as "None".

This is what I have so far, with the last line being an attempt to get the high temps only:

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://usclimatedata.com/climate/binghamton/new-york/unitedstates/usny0124"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
data = soup.find("table", {'class': "align_right_climate_table_data_td_temperature_red"})
```

Comment: This is probably a question better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kuanb nope, on codereview it would be quickly closed - they review *working code only*.

Comment: Ah, thanks @alecxe. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, these are two different classes - `align_right` and `temperature_red` - you've joined them and added that `table_data_td` for some reason. And, the elements having these two classes are `td` elements, not `table`.

In any case, to get the climate table, it looks like you should be looking for the `div` element having `id="climate_table"`:

```
climate_table = soup.find(id="climate_table")
```

Another important thing to note that there is a potential for the "timing" issues here - when you get the `driver.page_source` value, the climate information might not be there. This is usually approached adding an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) after navigating to the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://usclimatedata.com/climate/binghamton/new-york/unitedstates/usny0124"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    browser.get(url)

    # wait for the climate data to be loaded
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "climate_table")))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
    climate_table = soup.find(id="climate_table")

    print(climate_table.prettify())
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Note the addition of the `try/finally` that would safely close the browser in case of an error - that would also help to avoid "hanging" browser windows.

And, look into [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) that can read your climate information table into a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe) auto-magically.