# Parse javascript website with Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do a bit of scraping on my local library's site, specifically the search results screen. Here's an example URL of what I'm trying to parse: https://catalog.denverlibrary.org/search/searchresults.aspx?ctx=1.1033.0.0.6&type=Keyword&term=How%20Not%20to%20Die&by=TI&sort=RELEVANCE&limit=TOM=*&query=&page=0&searchid=3

Best I can tell, the site needs javascript enabled and I can't quite get it enabled for my purposes. Here's the relevant code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://catalog.denverlibrary.org/search/searchresults.aspx?ctx=1.1033.0.0.6&type=Keyword&term=How%20Not%20to%20Die&by=TI&sort=RELEVANCE&limit=TOM=*&query=&page=0&searchid=1')
driver.implicitly_wait(1000)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

When I look through what was printed from the Soup, I see the text

> JavaScript has been disabled in your browser. Please enable JavaScript
>   in order to enjoy all the features of this site.

I feel like I'm missing something basic for how to get Javascript enabled, but I can't find it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could enable JavaScript with the profile option for selenium Firefox.

```
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True)
```

Here is how to do it.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0")
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True)
broswer = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
broswer.get('https://catalog.denverlibrary.org/search/searchresults.aspx?ctx=1.1033.0.0.6&type=Keyword&term=How%20Not%20to%20Die&by=TI&sort=RELEVANCE&limit=TOM=*&query=&page=0&searchid=1')
driver.implicitly_wait(1000)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Is it worth noting that when Firefox opens as a result of this code it does render properly with all of the search results?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, just the search portion of the page hadn't finished loading. So, I added this line of code to get it working

```
WebDriverWait(broswer, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located( ( By.ID, "searchResultsDIV" ) ))
```

Found it from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520524/parsing-a-website-with-beautifulsoup-and-selenium).